# How to add an AngularJS directive to the element object during a directive's link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I built two custom directives, datepicker and date-validation, and I'm having trouble with getting datepicker to include the date-validation directive. At first I had the datepicker  and date validation directives as...

```
controls.directive('dateValidation', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {  
            // validation methods here...
        }
    };
}]);

controls.directive('myDatepicker', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text"  date-validation />',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // inject date picker here...
        }}
    };
}]);
```

and this worked perfectly until I tried it in IE8. In IE8 it has a problem with the way the directive replaces the current element with the template and throws an error.

I then tried making replace equal false and took away the template. Then adding the "date-validation" attribute with jQuery and re-compiling the element using the $compile method like...

```
controls.directive('myDatepicker', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.attr({ 'date-validation': '' });
            $compile(element)(scope);

            // inject date picker here...
        }}
    };
}]);
```

But this didn't work either.

Also, the HTML that uses the directive looks like this...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="startDate" my-datepicker />
```

If anyone can advise me on how to include another directive inside a custom directive I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Anyone? Bueller??? Bueller???

Comment: What you can do is have your child directive depend on it's parent directive using require

Comment: But I would rather make it where both directives do not have to be added to the element.

Comment: You can use require for optional dependencies as well

Comment: So would using require automatically include the directive without having to type it in HTML file? That's what I'm trying to do.